# Python - Counting number of visits a user has made

Tags: python, file, text, store

I'm working on a program and I'm coming to the end of it and I've just implemented into my chatbot the ability for the bot to remember the users who have already spoken to them. Was easily done by saving the name the user gives my chatbot to a text file, but to end my program, I would love to be able to track how many times the user has spoken to my chatbot, but I'm not sure how to do it.

I know it'll need to be stored in a text file, but how do I give each user their visit count?

```
#Defining the YouTube Channel function
def Maximus():
    #Holding the end user's name to make the chatbot more friendly
    userName = raw_input ("\nPlease enter your name: ")
    if userName in open('usernames.txt').read(): #Checks to see if user is pre-existing
        print ("Welcome back, %s. Good to see you again!" % (userName)) #If user is pr-existing, send this message
    else:
        print ("Nice to meet you %s, I'm Maximus, the friendly bot that helps to answer any questions you may have about YouTube's website!\nType quit to go back to the main menu." % (userName))
        fw = open('usernames.txt', 'a')
        fw.write("%s\n" % (userName)) #Creates the new user, which Maximus remembers
        fw.close()
```

[image]

Where that "Welcome Back" message displays, at the end of it, I'd like to display the number of times the user has logged in to speak with the chatbot

Comment: What have you tried so far? You can use a [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

Comment: @Bahrom It's my first time writing into a file since I've just started picking up Python so other than saving the usernames into a file, nothing else

Comment: Post your code so far (just the essential pieces). Having a sample input/output helps. The question is rather broad this way. How are you writing the names for instance?

Comment: Take a look at the [`shelve` module](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/shelve.html).

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`json`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) module to store a dictionary with names as the keys and number of visits as the values.

```
import json


def Maximus():
    # Holding the end user's name to make the chatbot more friendly
    userName = raw_input("\nPlease enter your name: ")

    with open('usernames.txt', 'r') as f:
        userCounts = json.load(f)

    if userName in userCounts:
        userCounts[userName] += 1
        print ("Welcome back, {}. Good to see you again! "
               "This is the {} time you have spoken to me.".format(
                   userName, userCounts[userName]))
   else:
       userCounts[userName] = 1
       print ("Nice to meet you {}, I'm Maximus, the friendly bot "
              "that helps to answer any questions you may have "
              "about YouTube's website!\nType quit to go back "
              "to the main menu.".format(userName))

    with open('usernames.txt', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(userCounts, f)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do it through web you could use cookies? Otherwise I'd say do it through the JSON module as mentioned above